# What does "func.QueueMessage) -> None:" do in python?

Tags: python, azure

In an python azure function i need to upgrade i got:

```
def main(msg: func.QueueMessage) -> None:
```

def main - is the entry point of the program , and main is a function name. But other then that i'm blank.

What does the rest of the code actually mean/do?

Comment: The function parameter is named `msg`, its type hint is `func.QueueMessage`, and the function returns `None`.

Comment: Those are type hints https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html